# Unique weapons locations

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have found some unique weapons throughout the game, but far from all. They just seem to appear at *random* locations (like on the ground in a cave).

Is there any hints or tips one can follow to find these weapons? (Without cheating, obviously).

Comment: SHould I take by "Without Cheating" that you don't want a guide?

Comment: I wasn't planning for a list of locations, but heck, if there isn't any way to determine the locations of those weapons, why not. I just thought it would have been fun to go on a mighty quest for each and every one of the weapons, but without any trails to follow, it isn't worth the time, I guess. :)

Comment: I'm not going to simply copy the list into an answer, I don't think there's any real benefit to me doing so, but I *will* point you to The Vault's Fallout:New Vegas subsection, which contains a list of all the available weapons in the game. Unique weapons are *Highlighted*: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_weapons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They may appear random ([LOVE/HATE](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Love_and_Hate) for example drops from a seemingly random raider captain. [Annabelle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Annabelle) drops from a seemingly random nightkin). However, they're not actually random. If you play through it again, you'll find the same drops in approximately the same place.

The only way to really find them all is to exhaustively search the world. Yuck. I don't recommend it. Really though, you don't have to go through that hell. The "special" weapons are better than the un-upgraded versions of the normal weapons, but they're not significantly better than the upgraded versions. And some of the best weapons (the anti-materiel gun, and the fat man) don't even have special versions.

So use what you like, and keep an eye out for weapon mods.

One thing I will say: if you're looking for *good* weapons, expect to jump through a few hoops. It's rare that you can just kill someone and they've got a great weapon (I like Love/Hate, and all, but there is a big difference between the elite brass knuckles and the elite gauss rifle, which is a bad example, because that's a drop as well.) It's more likely you'll have to pick a 100 skill lock, or hack a 100 skill computer, and that lock and that computer will probably be significantly off the beaten path.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was random as in random fixed positions, I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: Annabelle is quite awesome. And its owner is not really random, it's the only enemy in the game called a Nightkin Sniper.

Comment: @wilerson: I've yet to use a character that uses heavy weapons. I'm thinking of doing that next. Still, first time I saw him, I splattered him all over his silly tower before he even saw me, and didn't realize until later he had a big gun, so, at least for me, he didn't stand out.

Comment: @Wilerson - Everyone knows that rocket sniping is the best kind of sniping.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy The biggest problem with heavy weapons is that they're heavy - Annabelle + 10 missiles = 30 pounds.

Comment: @wilerson: Yea, I'm thinking of doing a melee/explosives build. As long as I'm not using bumper swords, the melee stuff is pretty light.